# How to generate list of values that sum to X given n spots where each value is unique.

Tags: combinatorics

For example: Given 2 spots and sum 3 the list would be {1,2}

Given 2 spots and sum 4 list would be {1,3} does not contain 2 as putting 2 in both spots violates the uniqueness of each value.

Comment: A greedy search should be efficient here. Note that the number of such partitions of $X$ is the $t^X$ coefficient of $\prod_{\lambda = 1}^{\infty} (1 + t^{\lambda})$, and the of these numbers is http://oeis.org/A000009 .